# How can I configure EditTextPreference to have scroll bar

Tags: android

In my android application, I have a EditTextPreference as one of my preferences in my PreferenceActivity. My question is how I can add a 'scroll bar' for the text of the EditText Preference? Sometime when the text is too long and when the 'soft keyboard' pops up, I don't see the buttons of the edit text dialog.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access the EditText of the EditTextPreference programmatically via `getEditText()` and then call `setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())` on your EditText to make it scrollable.

Or you can set any EditText attributes on the EditTextPreference XML like `android:scrollbars="vertical"`.